# Format number using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I need an assistance , I am new in this.

I have a column called "Driver" with the following number  "01234567899".(11 numbers)

I want to select only  10 numbers and add "-" without update the database, the final outcome will be as following :    1-2345678-99

any ideas how to help me here .... I am new in this

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using MySql you should look at its list of String functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

```
SELECT CONCAT(substring(driver, 2, 1), '-', substring(driver,3,7), "-", substring(driver, 10)) AS your_number
FROM your_table;
```

I didn't test it but it should work.
If you need something a bit more complicated you might want to look at the regexp function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, didn`t solve the issue yet...